# CSCore crashes when "soundOut.Play" is called from inside Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cscore

When trying to play a sound with CSCore loaded inside a Unity3D project, the editor terminates.

```
        IWaveSource audio = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(pathToMP3File);
        ISoundOut device = new WasapiOut();
        device.Initialize(audio);

        device.Play(); // the call causing the crash
```

Which output I choose (WasapiOut, DirectSoundOut, WaveOut) does not change the result.

---

CSCore.dll has been compiled with "Unity 3.5 .net Full Base Class Libraries" target setting in VS 2015. This is the complete script:

```
using UnityEngine;

using CSCore;
using CSCore.Codecs;
using CSCore.SoundOut;
using System.Threading;

public class CScorePlayback : MonoBehaviour {

    static string testAudio = "C:/Path/to/audio.mp3";

    IWaveSource audioSource;
    ISoundOut audioDevice;
    Thread audioThread;

    void Start () {
        audioThread = new Thread(PlaySoundTest);
        audioThread.Start();
    }

    void PlaySoundTest()
    {
        audioSource = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(testAudio);
        audioDevice = new WaveOut();
        audioDevice.Initialize(audioSource);

        try
        {
            audioDevice.Play();
            Debug.Log("Sound Played!");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error playing sound: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (audioThread != null) audioThread.Join();
        if (audioDevice != null)
        {
            audioDevice.Dispose();
        }
        if (audioSource != null)
        {
            audioSource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have in your question, does it work in Visual Studio? I don''t mean Unity. I mean compiling it with MS Visual Studio. Does it work there?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, the code works in a regular C# project.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest you do is to put the `Play()` function that crashes in a try catch block.

```
void Start()
{

    IWaveSource audio = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(pathToMP3File);
    ISoundOut device = new WasapiOut();
    device.Initialize(audio);

    try
    {
        device.Play(); // the call causing the crash
        Debug.Log("Sound Played!");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error playing sound: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

If it crashes, please see check if there a message printed out. Edit your question and post the error message.

Now also try to call the whole function in other Thread to make sure that is not the problem. Let me know what happens in the both instances.

```
void Start()
{
    playSound();
}

void playSound()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(___playSound)
    {

    }.Start();
}

void ___playSound()
{

    IWaveSource audio = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(pathToMP3File);
    ISoundOut device = new WasapiOut();
    device.Initialize(audio);

    try
    {
        device.Play(); // the call causing the crash
        Debug.Log("Sound Played!");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error playing sound: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately in both instances the result is the same. The editor terminates with no message shown in the attached Visual Studio except `Application "Unity" closed with code 0`.

Comment: @Appleshell If you comment out the Play() function, does it still close?

Comment: No, it's certainly the call to `Play`.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/SoundOut/WaveOut.cs

Comment: @Appleshell Didn't see anything weird in the source code. Can you update your question with your whole Unity code? I will give it a try when I have time and return to you if I find anything.